# How to use RegularExpressionValidator to validate Image extension in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, file-upload

```
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FUpImg1" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" />

                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="FUpImg1" ValidationExpression="(.*?)\.(jpg|png|JPG|PNG)$"
                    CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Please Upload .jpg, .png only" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

its not working its directly going on server side not validate my image extension. what is wrong with above code?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not going to be able to use a regex validator for that. Which property of FUpImg1 are you validating against - do you know ? It's not in your example. I would look into using a CustomValidator instead, even though you will have to hand-roll JavaScript as well as the server-side validation.

Comment: why i can't use reqex for this when it validate mails? i never declare any property when use for textbox or dropdownlist. i haven't learn js yet.

Answer (score 0):

RegularExpressionValidator only validate when i upload anything in the FileUploader!
that why its not validate anything when its null and going on server side in my question.

i use customvalidator with js function because i have 5 different FileUploader and i have to pass same function.

```
function validateImageExtension(source, args) {
     var reg = /^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.jpg|.png|.jpeg)$/;
                if (args.Value == "" || args.valueOf == null) {
                    args.IsValid = false;
                    source.innerText = "Image is Required*";
                }
                else {
                    //Checks with the control value.
                    if (reg.test(args.Value)) {
                        args.IsValid = true;
                        source.innerText = "";
                    }
                    else {
                        //If the condition not satisfied shows error message.
                        args.IsValid = false;
                        source.innerText = "Only .jpg, .png, .jpeg  files are allowed!";
                    }
                }
 }
```

idk how it work btw. i just copy paste it from 5 different blogs.